# If $g$ and $h$ are primitive roots of an odd prime $p$, then $g = h^k \pmod p$ for some integer $k$. Show that $k$ is odd.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-explanation

If $g$ and $h$ are primitive roots of an odd prime $p$, then $g = h^k \pmod p$ for some integer $k$. Show that $k$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

If $k=2m$, then $h^k$ has order at most $\frac{p-1}{2}$ and so cannot be a primitive root.